# Difference between 'for index' and traditional 'for loop'

Tags: swift, loops, for-loop

I'm new to Swift and pretty new to programming. I'm not sure if it's because it's 2:34 am but can somebody help me identify the difference between these two loops?

The first one is resulting in the values I want yet uses (as the Swift documentation explains) a 'traditional C loop' where the one after is using what seems like a Swift preferred 'for index' loop (which I personally like as it is clearer to me), the problem is that this loop returns every number rather than meeting the conditional.

```
func findLargestPrimeFactor(number: Int) {
    for var i = 2; i < number; i += i {
        if number/i % 1 > 0 {

        } else {
            print(i);
        }
    }
}

findLargestPrimeFactor(13195);
```

Below is returning every number to 13195

```
func findLargestPrimeFactor(number: Int) {
    for i in 2...number {
        if number/i % 1 > 0 {

        } else {
            print(i);
        }
    }
}

findLargestPrimeFactor(13195);
```

Comment: Your first function adds `i` to itself at each iteration. The second function doesn't, it just increments `i`.

Comment: Side note: `number/i % 1 > 0` makes no sense because it is never true. Neither of your function computes the largest prime factor of the given number. – Are you working on https://projecteuler.net/problem=3 ? :)

Comment: @MartinR You're exactly right, I realised this as I submitted my question but didn't want to edit it too early till I had the solution. I feel very stupid now (Like I mentioned, it's fairly late :p)

Comment: the biggest difference is the fact that the c style iteration will be removed from Swift in the fall when 3.0 comes out.

Comment: @MartinR Oh and yes I am :) I'm a designer trying to get a grasp of development!

Answer (score -1):

I've realised how stupid my mistakes were, first of all I have no idea why I was doing i += i, that just didn't make sense at all.

Also, my conditional was never being met because I declared it as an Int when really I needed a Float because I care about remainders!

Edit: I've updated my code yet again (taken everyones feedback into consideration), I feel a bit better with this and will continue working on the solution.

Thanks to everyone for your help!

Updated code

```
func findLargestPrimeFactor(number: Int) {
    for i in 2...number {
        var n = Float(number)
        var count = Float(i)
            if n/count % 1 > 0 {
                print("not divisible")
            } else {
            print(i)
        }
    }
}

findLargestPrimeFactor(13195);
```

Comment: Do not use floats in for loops. To see if a number can be divided by another one simply use (number % i == 0). Also do not use C-style loops as they will be removed from Swift in the next version.